# Use ng2-adal to get access token for Microsoft Graph Client

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, adal.js

I'm trying to create an Angular application that uses the [Angular 2 ADAL library](https://github.com/sureshchahal/angular2-adal) to login into Azure Active Directory and afterwards call [Microsoft Graph Client](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript) to retrieve some informations about the current user.

Unfortunately the Graph client always returns `InvalidAuthenticationToken` and I don't know how to further investigate to find the root cause.

**my.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

import * as MicrosoftGraph from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types';
import { Client } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client';

import { SecretService } from '../../shared/secret.service';
import { AdalService } from 'ng2-adal/services/adal.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my',
    templateUrl: './my.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    isBrowser: boolean;
    private graphClient: Client;
    private userProfile: any;

    constructor(
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object,
        private adalService: AdalService,
        private secretService: SecretService) {
        this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
        adalService.init(secretService.adalConfig);

        // Don't initialize graph client in server-side-rendering
        if (this.isBrowser) {
            this.graphClient = Client.init({
                authProvider: (done) => {
                    done(undefined, this.adalService.getCachedToken(this.secretService.adalConfig.clientId));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
        if (!this.isBrowser)
            return false;

        return this.adalService.userInfo.isAuthenticated;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Fast exit on server-side-rendering
        if (!this.isBrowser)
            return;

        // Initialize ADAL service
        this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
        this.adalService.getUser();

        // If we are already logged in (cause reply url is called from login)
        // use Graph API to get some data about the current user
        if (this.isLoggedIn) {
            this.graphClient.api('/me').get().then((value) => {
                this.userProfile = value;
            }).catch((error) => {
                // Currently I'm always getting here, but never in the above then() call.
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }

    onLogin() {
        this.adalService.login();
    }

    onLogout() {
        this.adalService.logOut();
    }
}
```

**my.component.html**

```
<md-toolbar>
    <md-toolbar-row>
        <button color="primary" md-button *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" (click)="onLogin()">
            Login
        </button>
        <button color="accent" md-button *ngIf="isLoggedIn" (click)="onLogout()">
            Logout
        </button>
    </md-toolbar-row>
</md-toolbar>
<md-card>
    <md-card-content>
        <section>
            {{userProfile}}
        </section>
    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code, you were calling the Microsoft Graph using the id_token issued from Azure AD. To call the Microsoft Graph, we need to use the access_token and its audience should be `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

You need to acquire the access_token for the Microsoft Graph using the code like below:

```
this.adalService.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com").subscribe(function(token){
          this.graphClient = Client.init({
            authProvider: (done) => {
                done(undefined, token);
            }                
        });
```

More detail about authentication of Microsoft Graph, you can refer the link below:

[Get access tokens to call Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview)

Comment: Okay, now I understood what a *resource* in the `acquireToken()` call should be. I changed my code accordingly and retried it. Now the `acquireToken()` call returns as error: `Token renewal operation failed due to timeout`. By looking into the network logger I can see a call to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/myDomain.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&...`, but that call gets as Status `(canceled)`. Any ideas?

Comment: Adal waits for 6 seconds to receive response from AAD. If AAD does not send a response at all or response was not sent as fragment, adal cancels the request giving the above error. Can you please check the network tab (in Developer Tools in Chrome) or fiddler to see if AAD returned a response to adal request. adal request is sent to login.microsoftonline.com and starts with authorize?

Comment: That's what I've seen (and already stated in my first comment). The only awkward thing is the time. It always has a value somewhere around 220ms to 400ms. I also tried the graph api endpoint declared in my azure portal (which is `https://graph.windows.net/tenant-GUID`). Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZJdO.png) from my network tab.

Comment: Since I am not able to reproduce this issue, would you mind sharing a runnable code sample to help reproducing this issue? You can upload it to the Github and please removing the sensitive information before you making the code sample public.

Comment: Okay. I'm going to publish a sample project. I'll inform you, when it's up and running.

Comment: Just uploaded my sample project [to git](https://github.com/olivermue/aspnetcore-angular2-universal/tree/ProblemWithGraphApi). The project can be run with `dotnet restore`, `npm install`, `npm run build:dev` and `dotnet run`.

Comment: Just forgot: Update your tenant and clientID in `Client - app -shared - secret.service.ts`

Comment: I am trying to run the project, however got the error like `route.resolver.ts (7,14): Class 'ConnectionResolver' incorrectly implements interface 'Resolve<SignalRConnection>'.` I am also upload the testing project from [here](https://github.com/VitorX/Angular2-MicrosoftGraph-AcquireToken). You can login-in using the Azure ad account and navigate to 'http://localhost:3000/graph'. In this page, you can get the access_token for the Microsoft by clicking the button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148492/discussion-between-oliver-and-fei-xue-msft).

Comment: @Oliver I have update the code and replied in your new thread, please check it whether it is helpful.

Comment: Hello, I am having the same issue. I have checked both github solutions, but none of the worked for me. @FeiXue have you managed to solve this issue and is you github silution latest? Thank you