# Use microsoft-graph-client in project with SystemJS

Tags: angular, systemjs, microsoft-graph-api, adal, adal.js

Currently I'm trying to get ng2-adal to work within my project, but I ran into [some trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905480/use-ng2-adal-to-get-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-client).

Fortunately I got an answer from [Fei Xue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5752362/fei-xue-msft), but it still hangs. By trying to reproduce the problem I published a sample project on [GitHub](https://github.com/olivermue/aspnetcore-angular2-universal/tree/ProblemWithGraphApi), but Fei had problems in the first run to get it to work and he provided a working sample from [his side](https://github.com/VitorX/Angular2-MicrosoftGraph-AcquireToken). I cloned the repo and tried it out and after removing the e2e test and updating rx.js to version 5.4.2 it worked.

Then I tried to add the [microsoft-graph-client](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript) to the project. Fei already added it to the package.json, so I just had to use it...

Within the file `microsoftGraph.component.ts` I imported the client and tried to use it by calling by this code:

```
   if (this.isLoggedIn) {
        this.adalService.acquireToken('https://graph.microsoft.com').subscribe((token) => {
            console.log(token);

            this.graphClient = Client.init({
                debugLogging: true,
                authProvider: (done) => {
                    done(undefined, token);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

As soon as I insert that code and build the project, I get an error message in the browser console (NOT from the compiler):

```
GET http://localhost:3000/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client 404 (Not Found)
```

so i started to configure the systemjs.config.js file within the project and added the map and package configuration:

```
map: {
    ...
    '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client': 'npm:@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src',
    ...
},
packages: {
    ...
    '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client': {
        main: 'index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
    ...
}
```

After build and reload I got some error messages, complaining about missing es6-promise and superagent:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/es6-promise 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:3000/superagent 404 (Not Found)
```

So I added but packages accordingly, like I added the graph client above. But this leads no to a pletora of missing packages (e.g. formidable, form-data, url, stream, mime, util, zlib, ...).

If I would continue to add all of them, I guess I would get further missing packages, down the road of all npm dependencies that each of these packages have declared.

**Conclusion**

I made something wrong and another way exists to configure system.js to make all this stuff automatically and not by hand. But how? Please give me some insights on how to configure system.js correctly to use the microsoft-graph-client.

Comment: I clone the repo https://github.com/VitorX/Angular2-MicrosoftGraph-AcquireToken and run npm install but cannot start. Could you please check?

Comment: Can run already, seem there is a problem of rxjs. So first I rename the secret.service.ts to the correct one and then add skipLibCheck into tsconfig. Will check your problem and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your error and also don't really understand why. I checked the @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client and saw that they have the dependency list which is matched with the library it tried to load. So let's see If there are any more answer from experts.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "^4.1.0",
    "superagent": "^3.5.2"
  }
```

One dirty way we can make it work is to refer to the js file on index.html. And add `declare var MicrosoftGraph: any` on the component when we need to use to bypass TypeScript check. I think you have already known about. After that just refer to the Javascript api with the usage like MicrosoftGraph.Client.xxx

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/libgraph-js-sdk-web.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, this is a know issue to load the `microsoft-graph-client` SDK using SystemJS( refer [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/issues/25)).

And to call the Microsoft Graph, I follow the code sample([msgraph-typescript-typings](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-typescript-typings)) using [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent).

Here is the changing code for for the `microsoftGraph.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig, AUTH_PROVIDERS, provideAuth } from 'angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt';

import * as MicrosoftGraph from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types"

import * as request from 'superagent';

import { AdalService } from 'ng2-adal/services/adal.service';
import {SecretService} from '../services/secret.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'MicrosoftGraph',
    template: `<button (click)="getProfile()">Get profile using Microsoft Graph</button>`
})
export class MicrosoftGraphComponent {

    private userProfile: any;

    constructor(
        private adalService: AdalService,
        private secretService: SecretService,
        private http1: AuthHttp) {
        adalService.init(secretService.adalConfig);

        }


   public getProfile(){
       this.adalService.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com").subscribe(function(token){
        console.log(token)

        request
            .get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me")
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
            .end((err:any, res:any) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err)
                    return;
                }
                let user:[MicrosoftGraph.User] = res.body;
                  console.log(user);

            })
       })
  }

}
```

Comment: How did you add superagent to SystemJS? If I only take your component.ts file I'll get within the browser an 404 for `http://localhost:3000/superagent`.

Comment: Finally I got your example to work, by adding the graph client library within the index.html and use the `declare var` call within the component.ts file. So now I'm having your example up and running and I can compare, why my doesn't work. :-)

Comment: It need to config for system.js using map like `"superagent":"node_modules/superagent/superagent.js",`. And for the project upload, I got the error like `route.resolver.ts (7,14): Class 'ConnectionResolver' incorrectly implements interface 'Resolve<SignalRConnection>'.
      Types of property 'resolve' are incompatible.` and not able to fix it. Did I have any mistake for this project?

Comment: I fixed the compile error on thursday. When you update, the solution should compile (the REST example doesn't work anymore, but that doesn't matter in our case).

Comment: Just retried it and currently you'll get an error from @angular/material. If you nail it to 2.0.0-beta.7 (where it was last week) than it compiles and runs fine (except that I won't get the token from adal).